# How to render a 2d image in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, java-2d

I have a quick question about Java. I'm sorry if this question is really basic, but I'm a beginner Java programmer :D

I want to render a 2d image in a window, but I can't figure it out. I've looked at the graphics API here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

and the only method I could find that might work is drawImage().
It wasn't working for me, though, but maybe it has to do with the ImageObserver Observer parameter? I just put null for that following some tutorial I found somewhere, but I still get a compile error:
Here is my paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("theImage.png");
    g.drawImage(img1, 100, 100, null);
} // public void paint(Graphics g)
```

and here are the methods that call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyGame game = new MyGame();
    game.setVisible(true);
    game.play();      

} // public static void main(String[] args)



/** The play method is where the main game loop resides. 
 */
public void play()
{
    boolean playing = true;
    //Graphics g = new Graphics();
    while (playing)
    {
        paint();
    }

} //  public void play()
```

The thing is when I call paint in the while loop, I get this error:
    paints(java.awt.Graphics) in MyGame cannot be applied to ()

What does that mean? How can I fix it so I can successfully render a 2d image?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Besides the other comments.  Don't load images in either the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods!  Load them at some other time (start-up is good) and store them as attributes of the class.  `ImageIO` offers a blocking method for loading images as well.  Easier than adding a `MediaTracker` to the image load after calling the `Toolkit` method..  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `paint();` use `repaint();`

Comment: THAT WORKED!!! omg thank you so much, I was working on this for at least 3 hrs last night and I could't get it to work, but now it does!! THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

You should be overriding [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)). Also, as [@TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960791/how-to-render-a-2d-image-in-java/6960834#6960834) suggested, you should be invoking [`repaint()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()).

Comment: When do paintComponent(Graphics g), it not longer works (but just using my code from above does with repaint())...

Comment: I agree that using `paintComponent(Graphics)` is a recommended practice. Although for very simple things (prototypes and throwaway things) I often am guilty of sneaking it in paint instead of paintComponent. :-X

Comment: @Steve, That's because a container doesn't have a `paintComponent` method. You should be overriding the `paintComponent` method of its content pane, or setting your own `JPanel` instance as the content pane, and then overriding its `paintComponent` method.

Answer (score 1):

- You overrid the paintComponent(Graphics g)

class Game extends JComponent { // Your game class

```
Image img = null;

public Game() {
   img = getImage("/theImage.png");
}
```

private Image getImage(String imageUrl) {

```
try {

    return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imageUrl));

} catch (IOException exp) {}

return null;
```

}

paintComponent(Graphics g) {

```
   g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, null);
```

}

}